# Redirect to parent domain, if I put / at the end of URL in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Route redirect to parent domain when I put / at the end of the URL

For example:
My base URL is: `http://localhost/pep_digital/`.

My URL is `http://localhost/pep_digital/dashboard`

When I put trailing slash `/` at the end like `http://localhost/pep_digital/dashboard/`

It redirects me to `http://localhost`

After visiting this link `http://localhost/pep_digital/dashboard/test/`

It redirects me to `http://localhost/dashboard/test`

And `https://localhost/pep_digital/dashboard/test/dashboard/test/`

It redirects me to `https://localhost/dashboard/test/dashboard/test`

It removing the 1st segment from the URL.

And the following routes I tried for all the issue is the same.

```
$routes->group('dashboard', function ($routes) {
    // Other routes
});
```

or
`$routes->match(['get'],'dashboard', 'Dashboard::index');`
or
`$routes->get('dashboard', 'Dashboard::index');`

My `.htaccess`

```
# Protect .env
<Files .env>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
      RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

**Update**
Well, I have updated my `.htaccess` to the latest updated branch, https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/public/.htaccess

And then clear my cookies and cache and tried again and my issue got fixed.

Clearing cache is because the redirect was set to `R=301`.

Comment: What version of CI4 are you running? This was/is a known issue: https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/2445

Comment: Yes, I'm using CI4, and thanks this helped me as well.

Comment: There are versions of CI4, use following command : composer show "codeigniter4/framework" to know the exact version of CI4.